# Unable to connect to Magento SOAP API v2 due to “failed to load external entity” after giving IP restriction in .htaccess file

Tags: php, magento, soap, wsdl

I am unable to connect to the Magento SOAP API v2 using PHP. The error that occurs is:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/wsdl/1/' : failed to load external entity "http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/wsdl/1/"
```

I gave IP restriction in .htaccess file such that only I will be able to view the site while development.

When I remove the IP restriction from the .htaccess file it works fine.

Any help would would be great as it's mandatory keep IP restriction!

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to add the server's ip address to the whitelist as well.